# Regex to match and replace a character in a pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I would like to replace a character `"?"` with `"fi"` in a string.

I could write a generic str replace for this. But I want to replace the "?" only if it appears in between two A-Za-z character and avoid the rest

Eg., `"Okay?"` should be `"Okay?`" and not `"Okayfi"`

but

Modi?es should be Modifies since it has ? in middle

**What have I tried?**

`sentence = re.sub(r"(\?)\b", "fi", sentence)`

Please see here.
https://regexr.com/3nvk3

Seems to work fine in regexr. but doesnt work well in code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also, please add all the relevant code you are using. What is the Python version? Is the `sentence` a Unicode string or a byte string?

Comment: Sentence is a byte string decoded to utf-8. Python version 3.6

Comment: Ok, so the solution below should work alright. If it does not, please show the whole exact relevant code.

Comment: looks like an encoding issue? It works when I give a simple regex `re.sub(r"modi?es", fi, sentence)`. Basically replaces the word to fi. But doesnt seem to replace when given your regex or any regex for that matter. Used re.UNICODE while compiling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach here is to find the original text with the [`ﬁ` ligature](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=FB01) and read it in with proper encoding.

Otherwise, you will have to use some workarounds.

You may use `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` / `(?=[A-Za-z])` lookarounds:

```
sentence = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-zA-Z])\?(?=[a-zA-Z])", "fi", sentence)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bXHTjw/1). The `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` positive lookbehind matches a position immediately after an ASCII letter, and `(?!=[A-Za-z])` positive lookahead matches a position immediately before an ASCII letter.

Or, you may also use a capturing group with backreferences:

```
sentence = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])\?([a-zA-Z])", r"\1fi\2", sentence)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bXHTjw/2). Note that `\1` references the value captured with the first `([a-zA-Z])` group and `\2` references the value captured into Group 2 (`([a-zA-Z])`).

Comment: read the text with the exact ligature and replaced it! (first one) Thank you for the suggestion.